# Git - Parent branch had dropped some commits, how to sync the commits into child branch

Tags: git

[image: commit image]

just like the image show above, in branch1(Br1) had done drop the commit C, but branch2(Br2) still keep it, how to sync the commits log into branch2 when I need to merge Br2 into Br1

Comment: If `br1` no longer has commit C, then the tree diagram is wrong

Comment: The tree diagram is wrong, put the simply diagram here just show the situation i met. right now, `br1` A -> B -> D->E... and `br2` A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> H... If i do merge `br1` will add C again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rebase `br2` to get rid of the *old* branch if `br1` was rewritten to get rid of `C`. Assuming that both branches are local (and if they are remote adjust the instructions to use them):

```
git rebase old-commit-for-E br2 --onto new-commit-for-E-or-br1
```

`old-commit-for-E` is the old commit of `E` as you have it in `br2`. Then if you feel like placing the branch on top of `br1`, use it as the parameter of `--onto`... otherwise, get the **new** commit id for `E` and use it there.